# How to close the tab which is opened through Response.Redirect() in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

used the codes such as

```
 window.close();
```

or

```
parent.close();
```

or

```
self.close();
```

or

```
open(location, '_self').close();
```

or

```
 window.open('','_self');
    window.close();
```

or

```
 window.open('', '_parent', '');
     window.close();
```

or

```
 open(location, '_self').close();
```

which gives the error.
 `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.`
how i will solve it.

```
   protected void ibtLogin_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {
Session["uId"] = dtbUserAuthentication.Rows[0]["idx_Users"].ToString();
                    Response.Redirect("ApplyNow.aspx?Userid=" +   Data.Encrypt(uId), false);
}
```

Comment: How are you opening the window write that code in your question.

Comment: yes I have opened through  Response.Redirect("Page.aspx");

Comment: can you post your code for opening window.

Comment: I have added the code in the question

Comment: i already tried with all the given ways